# Android - frequent updates with Strings

Tags: android, string

I have a Service that sends out updates every few hundred milliseconds. I have a String that gets created each time with a description of the event ("Time elapsed is 32 seconds").  Unfortunately I can't just use ints because the content can change depending on the event (usually however it's the same event type) and the feedback is going back to the user. Is there a way I can statically reuse the same String so that there aren't 100s of String allocations per minute? Even if I reuse the same variable, ie:

```
mEventUpdate = "Time elapsed is " + time + " seconds";
```

I still see a lot of String allocations being made.

Comment: you should use StringBuilder rather string

Comment: @BirajZalavadia how come ? Can you elaborate ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least you can use `String.format()` to reduce the number of created objects:

```
mEventUpdate = String.format("Time elapsed is %d seconds", time);
```

Answer (score 1):

A `String` in Java is an unmutable object. Once created, you cannot change it any more. So if it really has to be a `String` there is no way to avoid the allocations.

Answer (score 1):

Use StringBuffer

> If you have a method returning a string, and you know that its result
>   will always be appended to a StringBuffer anyway, change your
>   signature and implementation so that the function does the append
>   directly, instead of creating a short-lived temporary object.

http://developer.android.com/training/articles/perf-tips.html#ObjectCreation

Answer (score 1):

I wont bother with a long answer, either use format like someone said or use the often-overlooked `StringBuffer` - which I use when joining large number of `String`s together, say in a loop, where using format wouldn't be possible.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/StringBuffer.html

(I like Android's reference because look it compared to that nasty Oracle's nasty one :P)

Answer (score 1):

Declare this as global static variable

```
public static StringBuilder mEventUpdate = new StringBuilder();

mEventUpdate.delete(0, buffer.length());
mEventUpdate.append("Time elapsed is ");
mEventUpdate.append(time);
mEventUpdate.append(" seconds");

// TO desplay

mEventUpdate.toString();
```

Comment: Doesn't the toString() create a new String?

Comment: no it will not create new string it just returns string representations of stringbuilder. Just try and see the effect in DDMS.